# How to delete all associations between object and group of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have:

```
user.rb
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
group.rb
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
post.rb
  belongs_to :group
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

When user click "delete group" app delete association between Group and User, and destroy it if nobody else use this group:

```
def destroy
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  remove_group_from_user(@group)
  if @group.users(true).empty? 
    @group.destroy
  end
end

def remove_group_from_user(group)
  user = current_user.id
  if user
    group.users.delete(user)
  end
end
```

But User has associated Posts in this Group. When Group-User association is deleted I need to delete all associations between User an Group's posts.

Something like:

```
group.posts.users.delete(current_user.id)
```

How to do this?

**UPDATE** 
Here is something, that works, but I don't like it at all. How to make it pretty?

```
def remove_group_from_user(group)
    user = current_user.id
    if user
      group.users.delete(user)
      current_user.posts.where(group_id: group.id).
                   each do |post| #from here
        post.users.delete(user)
        if post.users(true).empty?
          post.destroy
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the posts from a specific user in a group you could do

```
group.posts.where(user_id: current_user.id).destroy_all
```

This could also be added as a method to the post model like so

```
def self.by_user(user)
    where(user_id: user.id)
end
```

and then you could accomplish the same thing by calling

```
group.posts.by_user(current_user).destroy_all
```

I would however recommend to put this in callback inside each model instead to keep it cleaner. You can read more about callbacks here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: `group.posts.where(user_id: current_user.id).destroy_all` It will work if I have `user_id` column in posts table, but I have HABTM association, so things are different.

Comment: Ok, what if you change `user_id` to `group_id` since this is a one to many association. So you would run something like `current_user.posts.where(group_id: group.id).destroy_all`

Comment: yes, it works, but destroy an associated post. And I need to destroy only association between post and user. I make one variant, that works, but I don't like it at all. I'll update my question.